# Designing REST end-point(s) for GET request supporting different IDs

Tags: rest

I seek suggestions regarding designing an API endpoint.

I have a table (resource) with id (PK) and some other ids, which are not unique but have not-null constraints.

Now for designing this:

1. For the PK search `/<resourceName>/{id}`
2. Non-PK search

   2.1 `/<resourceName>/someOtherIdName/{someOtherId}` - using path param, distinct for different IDs

   2.2 or `/<resourceName>?<nameOfId>=<value>` - using query param

**For 2nd one, which way is better?** If I use 2.2, then multiple IDs can be supported but it becomes convoluted, as I have to check the `nameOfId`. And what about 2.1?

**Edit:** For example, take `transactions` to be a resource, and `txn_id` as primary key, and `txn_event_id` and `txn_activity_id` as other IDs. The last two ids can represent a group of related transactions. Does 2.2 suits for the last two IDs?

In case of 2.1, the implementation looks like:

```
@Path("/transactions")
class TransactionResource {
    @Path("/eventid/{event_id}")
    public List getTxnWithEventId(@PathParam("event_id") String eventId) {
        // do a "event_id" based search
    }

   @Path("/activityid/{activity_id}")
    public List getTxnWithActivityId(@PathParam("activity_id") String txnActivityId) {
        // do a "pin" based search
    }
}
```

In case of 2.2, the implementation becomes something like:

```
@Path("/transactions")
class TransactionResource {
    public List getTxnsWithAnotherId(@QueryParam("searchKey") String id, 
        @QueryParam("searchValue") String value) {
        if("event_id".equals(id)) // do a "event_id" based search
        else if("activity_id".equals(id)) // do a "activity_id" based search
        else return null;
    }
}
```

In my opinion, the 2nd option feels better for searches but why not the former if thats true?

Answer (score 0):

I think it all comes down to the developer's preference. I would not go with either of the options you listed. My approach would be `collectionId/resourceId/collectionId/resourceId`. So in your case, it would be something like `users/1/messages` to get all messages of a specific user of `users/1/messages/1` to get message with id of 1 for that specific user. That way, you create clearer API endpoints which can be routed more efficiently in your app and can be better documented and managed.

Have a look at how [Google's API Design Guide](https://cloud.google.com/apis/design/resources) approach this subject for their Gmail resource model:

```
A collection of users: users/*. Each user has the following resources.
A collection of messages: users/*/messages/*.
A collection of threads: users/*/threads/*.
A collection of labels: users/*/labels/*.
A collection of change history: users/*/history/*.
A resource representing the user profile: users/*/profile.
A resource representing user settings: users/*/settings.
```

Comment: please check the example i added

Answer (score 0):

> For 2nd one, which way is better?

Either of these is fine for most use cases

```
/<resourceName>?<nameOfId>=<value>
/<resourceName>/<nameOfId>/<value>
```

Tomato, tomato.

One reason that you *might* care about the difference is in the use of relative resolution and [dot segments](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#section-5.2.4).  Dot segments are useful for traversing the hierarchical portion of the URI, which is to say the path segments.

Another reason that you might care is that the [query part](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#section-3.4) of a URI has not always been understood to be part of the identifier.  [Old versions](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616#section-13.9) of the HTTP spec described exceptions to the caching rules when the query part was present.  In [the current standard](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc9111.html#name-calculating-heuristic-fresh), it shouldn't make a difference.

If you are struggling with readability of the URI with data encoded into the path segments, there are a number of spelling conventions that may help -- many derive ideas from TBL's work on [Matrix URI](https://www.w3.org/DesignIssues/MatrixURIs.html)s.  If your clients and servers have access to decent [URI Template](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6570) implementations, then a lot of the work has already been done for you.

Answer (score -1):

I am not sure what your resources are specifically but here are some tips that you can keep in mind while designing RESTful APIs

Identify what the primary resource is. 
For example: employees

In your first case, you'd then access employees as

1. `GET /employees`. To get all employees.
2. `GET /employees/1`. Get a specific employee with ID 1.

Search is specific to your needs. If you need to fetch multiple employees based on IDs, you could do

`GET /employees?id=1,2,3,4`

Alternately if you find that you will need to search based on more than one parameter, I'd recommend a POST

```
POST /employees/search

{
 id: [1,2,3,4],
 department: "computer-science"
}
```

Comment: Thanks for response, I have an idea about that. But it does not addresses the needs I mentioned in my question, you might want to take a re-look and give more suggestions.

Comment: Same principle applies to your other resource as well. Maybe you could share more context like what are your resources? Could you also share more details about the search? What’s the actual attribute you’d like to search on?

Comment: Using POST to get data is a distinctly non-RESTful approach and breaks caching.

Comment: Yup, my point is search is very specific to needs. There isn't a one size fits all approach to designing APIs for search

Comment: please check the example i added